# Dynamic jetpack compose ui created from arbitrary composables

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Can anyone recommend references to documentation or projects that construct ui from arbitrary composables? I've been googling variations of this post's title and not finding what I need yet.

My two areas of specific concern:

- Is it ok to emit a composable into a compose context like this
  example?
- Can I emit separate states and events into the same compose
  context?
- What's a reasonable way to propagate events out of the provided
  composables?

My current idea is where my team provides a list to host composables. The content of these rows is created and managed by other teams. I just provide the "hosting" of their composable content and they provide a class with an @Composable Render() function. The limitation here is that a team should be able to provide their content (and event hooks, navigation etc.) without needing to modify the content list's ui or view model. I was trying to follow an SOLID open/closed approach.

It seems like it's then just a matter of injecting these instances into the composable context via a flow.

Prototype:

```
interface MyContentEntry {
    suspend fun init()

    @Composable
    fun Render(myContentNavigation: MyContentNavigation)
}

interface MyContentNavigation {
    fun navigateTo(fragment: Fragment)
    fun navigateTo(content: @Composable (() -> Unit)?)
}

typealias MyContentEntryList = Array<MyContentEntry>

@Inject
lateinit var contents: MyContentEntryList

...

setContent {
    val state = viewModel.state.collectAsState()

    val emittedComposable = remember { mutableStateOf<@Composable (() -> Unit)?>(null) }
    val backButtonEnabled = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    BackHandler(backButtonEnabled.value) {
        emittedComposable.value = null
        backButtonEnabled.value = false
    }

    viewModel.event.CollectAsEffect { value ->
        emittedComposable.value = value.content
    }

    if (emittedComposable.value != null) {
        backButtonEnabled.value = true
        emittedComposable.value?.invoke()
    } else {
        MyContentCollection(contents, this@MyContentCollectionFragment)
    }
}
    
...
        
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        contents.forEach { it.init() }
    }
}

override fun navigateTo(content: @Composable (() -> Unit)?) {
    viewModel.navigateTo(content)
}
```

In this example, I'd allow those rows to render fullscreen content into the setContent{} if needed and give some basic navigation within the setContent{}.

Anybody else using a similar approach?